# Using python 2.7 - regex to find all CR character at end of lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a folder with about 50,000 text files in it, and I need to see if any of them have lines that end in the CR character only (not CR/LF, or LF) - hex 0x0D.

The following code doesn't return any results, and takes a LONG time to process.

```
import re
import os

rootDir = 'Z:\Archive\\20160701'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('--\nroot = ' + rootDir)

    for filename in rootDir:
        file_path = os.path.join(rootDir, filename)
        print('Searching file: %s' % filename)

        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            f_content = f.read()
            check = re.search('[\x0D$]', f_content, re.MULTILINE)
            if check:
                print check
                gotit = open('U:\Temp3\\foundit.txt', 'a')
                gotit.write(file_path + '\n')
                gotit.close()
```

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone can provide.  I know there's at least one file in the folder that has line breaks as the 0x0D character only.

Comment: Just use `r'\r(?!\n)'` but read the whole file in before.

Comment: You are opening files in text mode, which is converting all the line endings to `\n`; as detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on reading and writing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
for filename in rootDir:    # rootDir is 'Z:\Archive\\20160701'
```

Should be:

```
for filename in files:
```

If all the files are in one folder, as you said, it is easier to use `os.listdir` You don't need all the power of `os.walk` that gives you the whole tree under the root dir, including sub dirs, and files.

Now, as for using `regex` to detect the newline characters, the problem is that when Python opens the file in `'r'` mode, `read` or `readline` change the newlines all to be `\n`.

The option would be to open the file in `'rb'` mode:

```
LF = b'\n'
CR = b'\r'
CRLF = b'\r\n'

def sniff(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        if CRLF in content:
            newline = 'CRLF'
        elif LF in content:
            newline = 'LF'
        elif CR in content:
            newline = 'CR'
    return newline
```

*nix systems have the `file` command to determine the file type. `file` can detect the file type based on "magic number", extension, etc. so that determining the type of text file is a very trivial task for `file`

What kept me *waddling* for a while is when I tested a text file created on a mac using nano. I got `\n` instead of the expected `\r`, until I [found out](https://superuser.com/a/439443) that MacOS changed to `\n` in order to be Unix compliant, leaving the `\r` to legacy text files.

Hope this helps a bit.\n

EOF

Comment: The regex  I suggested was `r'\r(?!\n)'`. No need doubling the backslashes.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason, when I tried it it didn't work with one, I had to use two slashes. The file I tested it with, is a 520MB json file I downloaded, that happens to have \r\n sequences.